# Add an element(Int,Double...) at the end of an "Any" type list

Tags: scala, list, recursion

I'm trying to add an element at the end of "Any" type list ( List[Any] ).
I want to use a recursive function to build it the idea is "if I need of this element I'll append it, when the iteration is over my list will be complete".
In the following code the idea is "I have a List 'l' if the element 'elem' is at the head of 'l' I'll add its position, saved in 'index', as next element of the list 'ret'. Otherwise I'll check the next element and doing nothing (I'm using 'l :: support...' only to match the return kind as List[Any]). When 'l' is empty(or Nil) give me the list 'ret'.
At the end 'ret' is the list that contains the position of all the elements 'elem' found in the list 'l'".
This is very important : the list that I'm building is 'ret' in fact it is the return of recursive function!

I tried with "::","+:",":+" but they didn't work. The error was the same every time "error: value :: is not a member of type parameter Any".

```
object find{
    def support[Any](l:List[Any],elem:Any,index:Int,ret:List[Any]):List[Any]={
        if (l==Nil) ret;
        else if(l.head==elem) (l :: support(l.tail,elem,index+1,ret :: (index.asInstanceOf[Any])));
        else (l :: support(l.tail,elem,index+1,ret));       
    }
    def findIndices[Any](l:List[Any],x:Any):List[Any]={//I want to find all the elements "elem" in the list "l"
        val a:List[Any]=support(l,x,0,List[Any]());//I'll build my list using an auxiliary function "support"
        a;
    }
}
object main extends App{
    val l:List[Int]=List(1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5)
    val x:Int=2;
    val f:List[Int]=find.findIndices(l,x)
    println(f)
}
```

I'm opened to all the working solutions but please first try to respond to my question and explain how you're doing it and why.
I'm learning this language, I came from C and Java.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. Do you only want to add an element to the end of the list?, But then, why are you searching for indices? Second, this `def support[Any]` does not do what you think it does, for now you may just remove the `[Any]`. Third, since you are doing this for learning, you want a solution using only plain recursion on Lists, or are you open to solutions using built-in methods of the standard library _(or both)_?

Comment: Why can’t you just use list ::: value :: Nil No need or recursion.

Comment: I'm opened to all solutions @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. Wait I'll change the title, however I want to add an element at the end of a generic list. The element is the position of "x" in the list "l","x" can appear multiple times maybe "l=List(a,x,x,x,b,x)" my list 'll be "ret=(1,2,3,5)" all the positions of x in l. I hope that this explains better my question.

Comment: @feded ahh I now understood your question, I added an answer that may help you. However mr Jeremy took the consideration of writing an even better answer being as meticulous as possible! I advise you to look to both and thank mr Jeremy by accepting his answer and giving an up-vote _(If you can)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR One Line Solution:**

```
val list = List(1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5)
list.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == 2).map(_._2) //  List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Or name your variables with case notation:

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter { case(value,index) => value == 2 } map { case(value,index) => index }
```

Or use the collect method to combine filter and map:

```
list.zipWithIndex.collect { case (value,index) if value == 2 => index }
```

**Recursion**

If you really need to use recursion, there's an easy way and a hard way to do this, and it looks like you're trying to do it the hard way.  The hard way makes sense in this case, but I'll do it the easy way first to help show you what I'm doing and why.

So given a List

```
val list = List(1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5) // named list instead of l because l looks like 1.
```

We want a function `findIndices` such that `findIndices(list,2)` returns `List(1,2,3,4)`

I'm going to start by defining `findIndices` like this:

```
def findIndices(list: List[Any], element: Any): List[Any] = ???
```

Now there's a couple of things I want to change right away. First, your example uses a list of things with a single type, so this looks like a great opportunity to use a parameterized type.

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T): List[Any] = ???
```

Second thing is that no matter what is inside the list, the resulting list of indices will be integers because indices are integers.

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T): List[Int] = ???
```

So now I'm ready to work on the body of the method.  I know this needs to be recursive, and the general form of a recursive function is:

1. check for terminating case.
2. handle non terminating cases.

So my function is going to look something like this:

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T): List[Int] = {
  // if (terminating case) return termination
  // else if (check for next index of element) return index plus recursive call
  // else return recursive call
}
```

Filling in the blanks gives us something like this:

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T): List[Int] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) List.empty[Int]
  else if (list.head == element) 0 :: findIndices(list.tail, element)
  else findIndices(list.tail, element)
}
```

Unfortunately this code has a bug.  We're calculating the indices based on the ever shortening list, instead of the original list.  We can fix this by keeping track of the offset of the indices as we use shorter and shorter versions of the list:

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T, offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) List.empty[Int]
  else if (list.head == element) offset :: findIndices(list.tail, element, offset + 1)
  else findIndices(list.tail, element, offset + 1)
}
```

This method works as intended...for small lists only.  For very large lists, we will get a stack overflow.  The way to fix this is to make the method tail-recursive, so the program doesn't need to keep track of the stack as it makes each call.  This is what you seem to be trying to do in your question.  I called it the hard way, but once you have the non-tail recursive function, converting it to the tail recursive function is actually fairly straightforward and mechanical.

The top level function parameters remains the same:

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T, offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = ???
```

Inside the first function we define a new function.  This new function will have the same parameters as the old one, plus an accumulator.  This accumulator will allow us to pass the intermediate results of the algorithm down the stack to the next recursive function call, so the program won't have to maintain the call stack to keep track of every intermediate result.

The only thing our outer function will do is call the inner function with the initial parameters.

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T, offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = {

  def findIndicesAcc(list: List[T], element: T, acc: List[Int], offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = {
    // do logic here
  }

  findIndicesAcc(list, element, List.empty[Int])
}
```

The logic inside the accumulator function will be very similiar to the original function.  It will simply take advantage of the accumulator parameter instead of leaving the intermediate result on the stack.

```
def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T, offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = {

  def findIndicesAcc(list: List[T], element: T, acc: List[Int], offset: Int = 0): List[Int] = {
    if (list.isEmpty) acc
    else if (list.head == element) findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, offset :: acc)
    else findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, acc)
  }

  findIndicesAcc(list, element, List.empty[Int])
}
```

This function works as intended, but there are a couple of final bookkeeping and clean up items we can do.  First, we can get rid of the outermost offset parameter and take away the inner offset parameter's default value.  Second, we can add a `@tailrec` annotation to the inner function, to ensure that we've solved the stack overflow problem.  Third, if the order of the indices in the returned list is important, we can call reverse on the output of the accumulator.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def findIndices[T](list: List[T], element: T): List[Int] = {

  @tailrec
  def findIndicesAcc(list: List[T], element: T, offset: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (list.isEmpty) acc
    else if (list.head == element) findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, offset :: acc)
    else findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, acc)
  }

  findIndicesAcc(list, element, 0, List.empty[Int]).reverse
}
```

**More About Tail Recursion**

Tail recursion refers to a recursive function where the recursive call is the last thing that happens in the function.  Sometimes you have to look closely to see if something is tail-recursive or not.  For example, the code fragment

`else if (list.head == element) offset :: findIndices(list.tail, element, offset + 1)`

is not tail recursive because `offset` has to be prepended to the results of `findIndices` after it is returned.  This can be made more clear if we break each operation of the code fragment out into separate lines:

```
else if (list.head == element) {
  val tail = list.tail      
  val newOffset = offset + 1
  val recursiveResult = findIndices(tail, element, newOffset)
  return offset :: recursiveResult
}
```

When the code is broken down like this, we can see that more work has to be done after the recursive `findIndices` call returns.

On the other hand, the code fragment

`else if (list.head == element) findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, offset :: acc)`

is tail-recursive.  When we break the operations out into separate lines we get

```
else if (list.head == element) {
  val tail = list.tail
  val newOffset = offset + 1
  val combinedList = offset :: acc
  return findIndicesAcc(tail, element, newOffset, combinedList)
}
```

and we can clearly see that the `findIndicesAcc` call is the last thing that happens.

In the first case, the program is forced to maintain the entire call stack, because it needs to remember what the value of `offset` was in each prior iteration of the function.  In linux machines, we typically have 8 MB of stack to use.  For very long lists, we end up using up all 8 MB of the stack and this results in a stack overflow exception.

In the second case, all the relevant data is passed to the next iteration of the recursive function.  There is nothing in previous function call that the program needs to keep track of.  The compiler is able to detect this, and optimize the code into basically a loop.  In this case, there is no call stack to maintain, and so no risk of a stack overflow exception.

One last caveat, I checked this code as closely as I could, but I did not have access to a scala compiler when I wrote this, so I apologize for any typos.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, this is exactly what I was looking for...your exposition is so good, all is clear for me. Only one question : which is the difference between "(list.head == element) offset :: findIndices(list.tail, element, offset + 1)" and the second method " else if (list.head == element) findIndicesAcc(list.tail, element, offset + 1, offset :: acc) "? I understand that is something linked to how the stack works and its difficulties to keep tracks of all the recursive iterations, I imagine that but I don't know exactly how it works. Can you explain me this passage please?

Comment: I added a bit more of an explanation about tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn a bit more about generics in Scala. Particularly the idea of calling the generic parameter `Any` so it shadows the standard type `Any` is a very bad idea. Also it might help learning about pattern matching which is a powerful tool to replace some `if/else if/else` statements. I believe the code you want would looks like this:

```
object find {
  @tailrec
  def support[A](l: List[A], elem: A, index: Int, ret: List[Int]): List[Int] = l match {
    case Nil => ret
    case head :: tail if head == elem => support(tail, elem, index + 1, ret :+ index)
    // _ meas here we ignore head anyway so don't need a variable for that
    case _ :: tail => support(tail, elem, index + 1, ret)
  }

  def findIndices[A](l: List[A], x: A): List[Int] = {
    //I want to find all the elements "elem" in the list "l"
    support(l, x, 0, List.empty[Int]) //I'll build my list using an auxiliary function "support"
  }
}
```

You can try this code [online here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jm6CatOnROKvycgRQCBSxQ)

Note that I made some improvements but there a few more improvements possible. For example, typically such `support` method would be put inside the `findIndices` so it is not available from the outside. Also  `:+` is very slow on `List`s. Typically it is faster to build the result list by appending to the start and then `reverse` it once at the very end.

Comment: At the beginning it was "def support[T]" but there were so many problems that I changed "T" to "Any". However the problem is that "ret :+ index" doesn't work. Thank you for your response I don't think that this resolves the problem.

Comment: @feded If you think that renaming a generic from T to Any solves a problem, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: @feded Renaming `T` to `Any` does not change anything except for the fact that not the `Any`-type is shadowed. When you say "_the problem is that "ret :+ index" doesn't work_" do you mean your code or my code? It seems to work perfectly well in my code.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I tried maybe it could help, however I didn't believe in it for a second ahahah

Answer (score 1):

## Fully handmade solution

```
def reverse[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] = remaining match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs => loop(remaining = xs, acc = x :: acc)
  }
  loop(remaining = list, acc = Nil)
}

def findIndices[T](elem: T, list: List[T]): List[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T], acc: List[Int], currentIndex: Int): List[Int] = remaining match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs =>
      val newAcc = if (x == elem) currentIndex :: acc else acc
      loop(remaining = xs, newAcc, currentIndex + 1)
  }
  reverse(loop(remaining = list, acc = Nil, currentIndex = 0))
}
```

## Using standar higher order functions

```
def findIndicesStd[T](elem: T, list: List[T]): List[Int] =
  list.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == elem).map(_._2)
```

## Results

```
findIndices(elem = 5, list = List(1, 5, 3, 5, 8, 5, 5, 10))
// res0: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 6)

findIndicesStd(elem = 5, list = List(1, 5, 3, 5, 8, 5, 5, 10))
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 6)
```

## Explanation

Feel free to ask as many questions as you want, and I will edit this section with the answers.

However, I will answer a few ones I believe you will have now:

- **What does `@annotation.tailrec` mean?:** *In the code, nothing really. It is a compiler annotation which tells the compiler to check if the given function is recursive-by-tail, and if not emit a warning - it is more like a best practice to make sure the function will not blow up the stack*.
- **Why `T` instead of `Any`?:** *`T` here means a generic, it is like a type placeholder saying, this works for "Any" type. `Any` on the other hand is a concrete type (the super type of everything). They look similar, but the generic ensures you don't lose type information (if you have a List of Ints and you `reverse` it, it will get a List of Int, not of Any, back)*.
- **Why reversing the results?:** *Lists are great for prepending, but "horrible" for prepending - in general is always better to iterate them twice one for transforming and the other for reversing (Unless you use mutations like the internal implementations of List does... but that may break your program if you don't do it with care)*.
- **What does `_._1` & `_._2` mean?:** *The first underscore is used for anonymous functions, it means the first (and in this case only) parameter, `_1` & `_2` are methods (as you can see because they are being called with a dot `.`) on the `Tuple` class, they access the first and second elements of the tuple*.

Comment: I don't understand the point 4 "What does _._1 & _._2 mean?" can you explain me how anonymous functions work?

Comment: @feded If you look at the [_signature_ of the `map` method in **List**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):List[B]), you can see that it receives a function of one argument of type `A` to type `B`_(`A => B`)_ - thus you need to pass a function, one way would be to define a new `def ` and pass it... however, creating a new function every time and naming them is tedious, so **Scala** allows you to use anonymous functions like `x => x + 1`, in this case we name the parameter `x`, but given with only use once that could be written `_ + 1`.